# How to set a method's default argument to a class member

Tags: php, oop, class, class-design

I have this inside a php class:

```
$this->ID = $user_id;

public function getUserFiles($id = $this->ID) { } // error here
```

But apparently I am not allowed to use a property in this way. So how would I go about declaring that the default value of the method argument should be the value of the ID property?

There must be a better way than this:

```
$this->ID = $user_id;

public function getUserFiles($id = '') {
    $id = ($id == '') ? $this->ID : $id;
}
```

Comment: This class is very confusing to me. If it has the property of one user ID, then the instance should ideally be bound to a single user. At what point would I act on user 5 and expect to get user 8's files? That feels non-intuitive and, if I may make the leap, illogical in terms of proper OOP.

Comment: @erisco that's an interesting point. I was thinking that the method would default to the current user, but would be able to reuse the same method for another user. But I guess I was still thinking procedurally.  Are you suggesting that the better way would be to create another instance of the object for a different user?

Comment: I don't know about your design at large but from what I can extrapolate from this, yes, I would suggest having one instance per user. When you say "reuse the same method," that is what you accomplish by having multiple instances, as they all have the same methods available to them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually use null in this situation:

```
public function getUserFiles($id = null)
{
    if ($id === null) {
        $id = $this->id;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (for whatever reason and design), in a method, in the parameter default case, we just want to use an attribute instead, than I would also do it like Alex:

```
public function methodABC($param = NULL) {
    if ( $param === NULL ) {
        $param = $this->attributeUVW;
    }
    ...$param...
    }
```

...and here's the complete code to play with (my 2 cents):

```
<?php

    class MyClass
    {
    public $attributeUVW;
    function __construct() {
            $this->attributeUVW = 1234;
        }
    public function methodABC($param = NULL) {
        if ( $param === NULL ) {
            $param = $this->attributeUVW;
        }
        echo '<p>"'.$param.'"</p>'."\n";
        }
    }

    echo '<html>'."\n";
    echo '<body>'."\n";
    echo '<h1>class X</h1>'."\n";

    $x = new MyClass;
    $x->methodABC();
    $x->methodABC(5678);

    echo '</body>'."\n";
    echo '</html>'."\n";

?>
```

...prints:

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>class X</h1>
<p>"1234"</p>
<p>"5678"</p>
</body>
</html>
```